# Is it dangerous to disable 'Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions' when using an Ionic and Firebase App Check?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor, firebase-app-check

I have a mobile application project using Ionic and Firebase.

I primarily use the Firebase web SDK, and I want to implement App Check.

The issue is that App Check for the web requires a domain name, and iOS and Android applications do not have one.

The solution I found is to disable 'Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions' in my reCAPTCHA console.

I would like to know if this causes a security problem or if it makes App Check useless in my case.

(I wish to use only the Firebase web SDK, with Capacitor plugin or similar)